# Generating Model code with pwiz Error

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I am trying to generate some model values using pwiz. The database in question is a Sqlite database, which actually contains some Django tables in addition to some regular tables generated using a python script. However when I try the following in a Linux terminal

```
python -m pwiz -e sqlite -t mapping_table db.sqlite3
```

I get the following error:

```
/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3001, in get_indexes
for _, name, is_unique in cursor.fetchall():
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

The table I am trying to retrieve is one generated using another python script. It only has a couple of columns and rows in it. Not sure how to proceed here exactly.

Answer (score 0):

```
 python -m pwiz -e sqlite db.sqlite3 > db_map.py
```

pwiz reads the database and creates a file with the database mapping.

db.sqlite3 is the name of your database (put your database filename)

db_map.py is the filename of the output file (name it as you like but keep the .py extension)

Comment: I am still getting the same error. All you are doing is adding the output to a file.